# How to properly access AWS Secrets manager from CodeBuild with Maven and Nexus

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, nexus, aws-code-deploy, aws-secrets-manager

For the buildspec.yml (Generalized)

```
version: 0.2

env:
  secrets-manager:
    User: CodeBuild/Auth:User_Name
    Password: CodeBuild/Auth:Password

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo ${User}
      - echo ${Password}

  post_build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean deploy -Dnexus.user=$User -Dnexus.password=$Password
```

The echo commands give me *** which is masked so I think I'm good up to this point. Also, I'm using the DefaultEncryptionKey for AWS Secrets manager.

Inside of the settings.xml for Maven I have 
`<username>${nexus.user}</username>` and `<password>${nexus.password}</password>`

But when the mvn command runs it's returning a 401 authorization error...
I added AdministratorAccess to the CodeBuild role just in case, same 401 error.

If I declare the variables in clear text, the mvn command works. I'm just missing one thing but I can't find any documentation on how to get around this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
I switched everything over to parameter store and it worked with minimal adjustments. I would like to know what I've done wrong with setting up secrets-manager but I successfully got around this. I'll leave this here just in case someone else struggles with this.

Answer (score 0):

The format that you used to specify the secrets from secrets manager looks a bit off. Here's the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax.

The secrets are referenced as: 
key: secret-id:json-key:version-stage:version-id

Comment: I did generalize that part a bit but the formatting is/was correct.
User and Password are (key)
The secret-id in the example is:  CodeBuild/Auth
The secret contains 2 secret key/values User_Name/*** and Password/***
The json-keys would then be User_Name and Password.
version-stage and version-id are not required.

I verified that by setting up another key as UserPass, didn't use a json-key at all. echo response against that key showed both User_Name/*** and Password/***

Comment: Can you try to run '[ "$User" = "your-user-name" ]' to check if the $User environment variable contains the correct value?

Comment: Unfortunately since I got all of this working with Parameter store I don't have the codebuild job available anymore. I did try to set the environment variables though. When I listed them out though they still showed as ***. I think there must be some decryption on the build job itself but I couldn't figure out that process.